# How to preload cells below the screen in a GridView

Tags: java, android

I have a GridView with cells that take a few ms to load.  I want my GridView to recycle 2 pages worth of cells instead of one so that when the user scrolls down the cells are already there.

Comment: I would believe you can implement the ViewHolder pattern: http://www.javacodegeeks.com/2013/09/android-viewholder-pattern-example.html

Answer (score 1):

Are you loading images? If yes, I recommend you to use a library like this:
https://github.com/lucasr/smoothie